# React - Re-direct to a new domain

Tags: react-router

I have an app built in react and I am trying to implement re-direct where I need to redirect the user from my app base URL to a completely new domain.

Example:

React app base URL - "localhost:3001"
Redirect to - "www.google.com"

I am using react routes in my app.

ReactDOM.render(
        (

If I use Redirect as above, it redirects to "http://localhost:3001/#/http:/www.google.com"

How to get rid of base URL while redirecting to a new domain?

Comment: Sample code was trimmed off in my question, here's the code:

  ReactDOM.render(
        (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={hashHistory}>
                <Redirect from="/" to="http://www.google.com"/>
                <Route path="/" component={Nav} >

Comment: why arent you using a <a> tag? Where are you trying to redirect?

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca: below is the code where i'm trying to redirect
ReactDOM.render(
        (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={hashHistory}>
                <Redirect from="" to="http://www.google.com"/>
                <Route path="/" component={Nav} >
                    <IndexRoute component={home}/>
                    <Route path='/metrics' component={MetricsController} />
                    <Route path='/HealthMetrics' component={HealthController} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
          </Provider>

Answer (score 11):

**React-route only allows redirect to other routes**, you can confirm this by reading Github issue [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1062)

So the answer is **NO, YOU CAN'T**.

If I'm not misunderstanding your intention here, you want to redirect whatever which is not being handled by the router.

One aproach that comes to my mind as a solution:

**A component-dedicated:** Create a component dedicated for this route with a `componentDidMount` similar to this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.location.assign('http://github.com');
}
```

As an alternative, you can catch it directly in the server and redirect there.

But definitively you need to look for an alternative solutoin due `react-route` does not allow redirecting to externals url

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on an excellent answer by *Facino La Rocca*

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class DomainUrlRedirect extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        const{searchParams, pathname, url} = this.props
        let uri = new URL(url);
        uri.pathname = pathname
        for(const paramName in searchParams){
            uri.searchParams.append(paramName, searchParams[paramName])
        }
        window.location.assign(uri.href)
    }
    render(){
        return(<span data-test-component="DomainUrlRedirect"></span>)
    }
}

export default DomainUrlRedirect
```

You can leverage URL utility supported by modern browsers to construct your URL properly.

**Also, don't forget that the component will still try to render. Render it as part of some other component on condition so that object that uses it does not disappear.**

```js
render(){
  const{ redirectNow } = this.props;
  return(<div>
          <p>Important content</p>
          {redirectNow &&
             <DomainUrlRedirect {...url_params}/>
          }
  </div>)
}
```